# Reducing Interactive PDF Sizes

Tags: adobe-indesign

Does anyone know if it's possible to reduce an interactive pdf from MB to KB?

Let me explain. I was asked to design an interactive piece in InDesign to be sent out on email and usable via mobile that when you press on it, it will either open up a video or send you to a social media link. It has several social media links, and a couple of video links. Since it has all of this media- is it even possible to reduce the size?

Sorry- may seem like a dumb  questions but this is my first time doing this.

Answer (score 1):

External links will barely influence your file size. Most likely you will need to export to a lower resolution setting, meaning the photos in your document will have the biggest impact on the file size, so your best bet is to reduce the size of these.

To do so, look at the image compression area in the 'Export to Interactive PDF' dialog box and make sure you have 72dpi in the resolution field, and play around with the 'quality' setting.

Answer (score 1):

If you've got Acrobat Pro, then open the document in that and use `File > Save as Other > Reduced Size PDF...`

That's usually pretty good at stripping fat out of PDFs and getting their size down.